# What's the cheapest way to stay in Copenhagen?

Tags: sleeping, copenhagen, couchsurfing

A friend and I want to spend a week in Copenhagen to see the city. Copenhagen is ridiculously expensive and I am searching for a place to stay for both of us without bringing a sleeping bag with us. Airbnb is a hassle so I would prefer something else.

Comment: sleeping "under the bridge" would be the cheapest way :)

Comment: Be more precise about the kind of accommodation you expect: the comfort, the hassle. That's for sure, in general if you don't want to spend time on this, you will need to spend money. But that's your choice

Comment: If you're there for a week sightseeing, will you be venturing out of the city? If so, could you maybe spend some nights in smaller places which might well be cheaper?

Comment: You could get yourself arrested.  The government will then provide free accommodation with full board for the duration of your stay (although that duration may not match up with what you had originally planned). Sightseeing options may be limited by this option.

Comment: If you're clever enough, you might be able to sublet an apartment, or invest in some real estate, and actually make money staying in Copenhagen.

Answer (score 3):

The cheapest *hotel* that I'm aware of in Copenhagen (you can of course find much cheaper hostels) where you have your own private room and bathroom is [Cabinn](https://www.cabinn.com/).

They have several locations in Copenhagen, I prefer the one near the main train station, "Kobenhavn City Hotel" as they call it.

The rooms are small, but clean and reasonably comfortable.

The cheapest price for a two person room is 625 DKK total (i.e. for both guests), assuming they are not sold out for your dates.

While you may occasionally find as cheap and, more rarely cheaper rooms elsewhere, I've found Cabinn to be consistently right at the bottom range for hotels. I haven't stayed anywhere else in Copenhagen since 2005.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way to stay in Copenhagen (or, indeed, in any other city) would be by [Couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.org/).

Comment: I don't think "cheap accomation" would be the best reason to go couchsurfing. Then you can better go to a hostel.

Comment: @Bernhard I agree that it's not a good reason, but it still is the cheapest way.